# Does Hyperledger Fabric support native Rest API?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-chaincode

Does Hyperledger Fabric latest version (2+) Support out-of-the-box Rest APIs for accessing chaincode functionality?

Thanks,
Nihal

Comment: Use fabric-sdk. Build HTTP/REST API for each language of SDK and provide it in connection with fabric-client. If you want to connect the peer itself, you need to make it based on the peer's RPC. But that will soon be the SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Hyperledger fabric has SDK that you can manage your network and access chaincode functions with it, but it has not any native API that you can directly access the chaincode functionality. With fabric-sdk you can develop your API very easily. This sdk is available in many languages like javascript, java, python, go, ...